# jQuery send a query strings value as POST instead of GET

Tags: php, jquery

One of my php pages was changed to handle `POST` data (in order to accommodate a few form text fields), instead of `GET` (which was previously used).

So now, instead of `if($_GET) { }` it uses `if($_POST) { }`. They (team) wont allow both methods using `||`.

I need to send a querystring to that same page using jQuery, but because of `if($_POST) { }`, it will not get through.

The querystring is formed from this : `<i class="icon-hand remove" data-handle="se25p37x"></i>`

I used to send it using jQuery ajax before, but that will not work now. Any idea how I can send it as POST?

```
$('.remove').live('click', function() {

var self = $(this);
var handle = $(this).data("handle");

if(handle) {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST", // this used to be GET, before the change
         url:"/user/actions/"+handle,
    dataType:'json',

    beforeSend:function(html) {

    },
```

Comment: Your code worked for me. It successfully sent a POST request. Maybe you are overriding your settings somewhere using $.ajaxSetup?

Have you checked the Chrome Developer Tools? Is it really a GET Request or does your PHP script screw up?

Comment: url:"/user/actions/"+handle+"=1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `type: "GET"` to `type: "POST"` and add `data` parameter:

```
...
type: "POST",
data: $('form').serialize(), // OR data: {handle: $(this).data("handle")}
dataType: 'json',
...
```

Comment: Thanks. This `{handle: $(this).data("handle")}` solved the problem.